# React: Multiple waypoints Google Map API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

How can I dinamically track the addresses user types in inputs in stop-container so that those could be used as addresses for multiple waypoints? And also how to connect them with API so that those waypoints could be displayed? All I understand is when using AutoComplete component from Google Maps API the only way to track the address user eneters is by using e.current.value, e.target.value just won't do it. Here's the code:

```
    import { React, useRef, useState, Fragment } from "react";
import styles from "./RouteForm.module.css";
import KeyboardDoubleArrowDownRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardDoubleArrowDownRounded";
import CloseRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CloseRounded";
import PlaceIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Place";
import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";
import RemoveCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RemoveCircle";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useJsApiLoader,
  Autocomplete,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

const libraries = ["places"];

const RouteForm = (props) => {
  const originRef = useRef(null);
  const destinationRef = useRef(null);
  const stopRef = useRef(null);

  const [stopContainerVisible, setStopContainerVisible] = useState(false);
  const [directionsRes, setDirectionsRes] = useState(null);
  const [routeFormVisible, setRouteFormVisible] = useState(false);
  const [waypointInputList, setWaypointInputList] = useState([
    { waypointInput: "" },
  ]);

  console.log(waypointInputList);

  const handleRouteSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const origin = originRef.current ? originRef.current.value : "";
    const destination = destinationRef.current
      ? destinationRef.current.value
      : "";

    console.log(`Origin: ${origin}, Destination: ${destination}`);
  };

  const toggleFormVisibility = () => {
    setRouteFormVisible(!routeFormVisible);
  };

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: "AIzaSyBjizW_mGoQQI6jma6lTEWpaSsoYhKa6y8",
    libraries: libraries,
  });

  const toggleStopVisibility = () => {
    setStopContainerVisible((prevValue) => !prevValue);
  };

  const center = { lat: 42.4414, lng: 19.2624 };

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const handleWaypointAdd = () => {
    setWaypointInputList([...waypointInputList, { waypoint: "" }]);
  };

  const handleWaypointRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...waypointInputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setWaypointInputList(list);
  };

  async function calculateRoute() {
    if (originRef.current.value === "" || destinationRef.current.value === "") {
      return;
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const results = await directionService.route({
      origin: originRef.current.value,
      destination: destinationRef.current.value,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      waypoints: [
        {
          location: stopRef.current.value,
          stopover: true,
        },
      ],
    });

    setDirectionsRes(results);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={styles["form-and-map-container"]}>
        <GoogleMap
          center={center}
          zoom={15}
          mapContainerStyle={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
          }}
          options={{
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
          }}
        >
          {directionsRes && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directionsRes} />}
        </GoogleMap>

        <div className={styles.container}>
          <div className={styles.expand} onClick={toggleFormVisibility}>
            {routeFormVisible ? (
              <CloseRoundedIcon
                fontSize="inherit"
                className={styles["expand-icon"]}
              />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardDoubleArrowDownRoundedIcon
                fontSize="inherit"
                className={styles["expand-icon"]}
              />
            )}
            <span>Create Route</span>
          </div>
          <div className={styles["form-container"]}>
            {routeFormVisible && (
              <form onSubmit={handleRouteSubmit}>
                <div className={styles.inputs}>
                  <div className={styles["input1-container"]}>
                    <label>
                      <PlaceIcon />
                    </label>
                    <Autocomplete className={styles.input}>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Origin"
                        ref={originRef}
                        required
                      />
                    </Autocomplete>
                  </div>
                  <div className={styles["input2-container"]}>
                    <label>
                      <PlaceIcon sx={{ color: "#beff0a" }} />
                    </label>
                    <Autocomplete className={styles.input}>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Destination"
                        ref={destinationRef}
                        required
                      />
                    </Autocomplete>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.btns}>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={calculateRoute}>
                    Create Route
                  </button>
                  <span
                    className={styles["add-stop"]}
                    onClick={toggleStopVisibility}
                  >
                    Add Stop
                  </span>
                </div>
                {stopContainerVisible && (
                  <ul className={styles["stop-container"]}>
                    {waypointInputList.map((singleWaypoint, index) => (
                      <li key={index}>
                        {index < waypointInputList.length - 1 && (
                          <button
                            className={styles["remove-stop-btn"]}
                            onClick={() => handleWaypointRemove(index)}
                          >
                            <RemoveCircleIcon />
                          </button>
                        )}
                        <Autocomplete className={styles.input}>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Stopping place"
                            ref={stopRef.current.value}
                          />
                        </Autocomplete>
                        {waypointInputList.length - 1 === index &&
                          waypointInputList.length <= 4 && (
                            <button
                              type="submit"
                              className={styles["add-stop-btn"]}
                              onClick={handleWaypointAdd}
                            >
                              <AddCircleIcon />
                            </button>
                          )}
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </form>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default RouteForm;
```